# Bounds for the imaginary part of the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Let $\rho_{k}=\beta_{k}+i\gamma_{k}$
  the $k-th$
  non-trivial zero of the Riemann zeta funcion. We consider only the zeros with $\gamma_{k}>0$
 . Then we have$$\gamma_{1}=14.13...$$
 $$\gamma_{2}=21.02...$$
 etc. so it seems that holds $$\gamma_{k}>k.$$
 I checked the first 100 zeros and it seems to be true. Is it known? I haven't found anything like that on the internet.

Comment: You may be looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_zeta-function_conjectures or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg%27s_zeta_function_conjecture .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false. Recalling that $N\left(T\right)
 $ is the number of non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function with imaginary part $0<\gamma\leq T
 $, we know that holds $$N\left(T\right)\sim\frac{T}{2\pi}\log\left(T\right)
 $$ then we have $$k=N\left(\gamma_{k}\right)\sim\frac{\gamma_{k}}{2\pi}\log\left(\gamma_{k}\right)
 $$ and so$$\log\left(k\right)\sim\log\left(\gamma_{k}\right)
 $$ hence $$\gamma_{k}\sim\frac{2\pi k}{\log\left(k\right)}
 $$ as $k\rightarrow\infty
 .$