# Some doubts about easy computations involving nontrivial zeros of Riemann's zeta function

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

**On assumption of Riemann hypothesis** when I write **a complex zero (nontrivial zero) of zeta function** as $\rho=\frac{1}{2}+it_\rho$, and I write $x^\rho$ as $\sqrt{x}e^{it_\rho \log x}$, then multiplying and dividing by the conjugate of $\rho$ in a well known formula (see [1]) involving the **second Chebyshev function $\psi(x)$** we can write its real part $\Re\psi(x)=\psi(x)$ as

$$x-\sqrt{x}\cdot\Re\sum_\rho\frac{(\frac{1}{2}-it_\rho)\cdot(\cos(t_\rho\log x)+i\sin(t_\rho\log x))}{\frac{1}{4}+t_\rho^2}-\log 2\pi-\frac{1}{2}\log(1-\frac{1}{x^2}),$$
*when (the genuine equation holds only if) $x$ is not a prime power*.

Thus *if I can compute $\Re\sum_\rho$ as $\sum_\rho\Re$*, previous series (second summand) is computed as
$$\sqrt{x}\cdot\sum_\rho\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cos(t_\rho\log x)+t_\rho\sin(t_\rho\log x)}{\frac{1}{4}+t_\rho^2}.$$

Then, from previous formula, **Prime Number Theorem** implies (I've used **Dusart's theorem** that states (see [2]), unconditionally $\psi(x)=x+o(x)$)
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot\sum_\rho\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cos(t_\rho\log x)+t_\rho\sin(t_\rho\log x)}{\frac{1}{4}+t_\rho^2}=0.$$

My

> **Question.** (On assumption of Riemann hypothesis) I don't know if I have convergence to claim $\Re\sum_\rho$ as $\sum_\rho\Re$ in previous computations. I don't know if the condition that $x$ isn't a prime power it affects the computation of previous limit. Truly I don't know currently what is the answer to this question: if $\rho$ is a such zero (we are assuming RH) then I can claim that $t_\rho\to\infty$ as $|\rho|\to\infty$? I know that there is an heuristic about the number of such zeros with $t_\rho\leq T$, $\frac{T}{2\pi}\log\frac{T}{2\pi e}$, but I don't know sure nothing conditionally/unconditionally about how grows $t_\rho$. Thanks in advance.

**Remark:** I would like ask more, but I believe that previous set of questions  is more useful to me. If your want reference some in this site, please. I would like ask about if you can find an big oh asymptotic of previous series on assuption of RH. I don't know if it is an easy exercise. I've read, if there are no typo, that unconditionally  $|x^\rho|=\sqrt{x}$ and $\sum_\rho x^\rho=O(\sqrt{x}\log x)$. Too I would like to ask if it is possible find a proof of previous limit unconditionally, this is you could to use PNT, but not RH. My doubts are since, in previous computations, I use the theory and formula simbolically. Then if you want say something about this please leave a comment or if is a good question, in the sense that it is possible that I to learn easy facts and computations from answer, I could encourage to me asking a new question in a new post. Thanks.

**References:**

[1] Conrey, The Riemman hypothesis. The formula that I've cited is in first paragraph of page 343 of this free notes from AMS http://www.ams.org/notices/200303/fea-conrey-web.pdf

[2] Mathworld, Mangoldt function, **statement (12)** in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MangoldtFunction.html

Comment: I'm in hurry so I will take a look later about your calculations, but I can answer now about your last question. Let $t_{k}$ the imaginary part of the $k$-th zero of the Zeta function, then $t_{k}\sim\frac{2\pi k}{\log\left(k\right)}.$ For the proof see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217217/bounds-for-the-imaginary-part-of-the-non-trivial-zeros-of-the-riemann-zeta-funct

Comment: I am trying to understand all statements in your post,  when I have a concise question I will ask to you,  very thanks much @MarcoCantarini you are Great!

Comment: Now I've found your remark,  concerning this part of my question in the section **Counting zeros**, of al book of Murty, about Analytic Number Theory. I will too understand your assertion in you referenced post,  in I have doubts I write you,  thanks @MarcoCantarini now I dont disturb more.

Comment: I excuse to put a bounty [+50] going from myself reputation, since I would like to know if I can change the real part function with the sum, if I have convergence to claim it. If you want (optionally), since this is not explicit in my question, you can made a proof verification of previous claim involving the use of *Dusart's theorem*. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let answer your questions. The series over the non-trivial zeros is convergent, and you can see it simply because $\psi(x)$ is a number and you have an identity. If $x$ is a power of a prime there is no problem, in literature you will find this identity $$\psi_{0}\left(x\right)=x-\sum_{\rho}\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}-\log\left(2\pi\right)-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1-x^{-2}\right)$$ where $\psi_{0}\left(x\right)=\psi\left(x\right)$ if $x$ is not a prime power, $\psi_{0}\left(x\right)=\psi\left(x\right)-\frac{1}{2}\Lambda(x)$ if $x$ is a prime power, so no problem about the convergence. This formula came from a (non trivial) application of the [Perron's forumla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula), you can easily find it (but if you have problem I can give you some reference). Your calculation of the limit is right because, as you noticed, we know that holds $\psi(x)=x+o(x)$ and in the comment I wrote yesterday you can find a proof of the fact that $t_k\rightarrow\infty$ as $k\rightarrow\infty .$

Comment: Very thanks much @MarcoCantarini